# Apache installation

Tags: apache

I am trying to install Apache on windows 7. I have got following problem,

> httpd -k install

gives 'httpd' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.

I have given PATH for httpd file in environment variables as C:Apache24\bin.

Comment: Install XAMPP and make your life easier

Comment: Just `cd` to the folder that the bin file is located in. Did you use `C:Apache24\bin` or `C:\Apache24\bin`? Did you reboot your CMD afterwards (if you don't open up a new command prompt it will not get the new PATH's)?

Answer (score 2):

Put the folder with httpd.exe in PATH environment variable. Instructions are [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: There is no `httpd.exe` in `apache\bin` for me